# Facebook API get long lived token for native app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have currently flag my Facebook app as **Native or desktop app**, with **Is App Secret embedded in the client** set to **Yes**.
I can retrieve a short lived access token just fine, but when I try to exchange it for a long lived one, I get the following error:
`The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app`

My question is: is there a special flow to get a long lived token in this case or that's not possible by design?

Comment: There is no other flow.

Comment: so, if I can't it means that's not possible by design?

Comment: Yes, that is what the message implies.

Comment: Care to create an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: is there a special flow to get a long lived token in this case or that's not possible by design?

There is no other flow.

The message implies this is by design. They probably don’t see any need for using extended tokens in desktop apps. “The user is sitting in front of the thing, so if the short-lived token has expired, they can just go through the login flow again to create a new one.”